# URLforResource always returns nil

Tags: swift, xcode, filepath

I made a directory near `AppDelegate.swift` called `files` and put a `first.png` image there.

I ran this code

```
let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("first", withExtension: "png", subdirectory: "files")
```

and fileURL turned out to be nil. I tried to upload image in `Assets.xcassets` but it returns nil too .

What the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The `subdirectory` argument assumes that you've added `files` as a folder reference (it will show blue in Xcode) and not a group (it shows yellow). This option comes up when you drag the folder into Xcode to add it.

If it's a group, then anything inside it will be added to the bundle resources at the top level.

You can check where the file has ended up by looking at the package contents of your built project, there will be a folder called "Resources" which will contain all of your resources.

Comment: I added in `Build Phases->compile sources` my directory and  it works. Thanks.